# Find the last modified file on FTP site using powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I am trying to get the name of the last modified file (and subsequently download later) on the FTP site through powershell. But I am unable to get the results. If someone can point me to the right direction, that would be really great. Thank you very much.

---

$ftpPath = 'ftp://ftpsite/'

function Get-FtpDir ($url)
{
  $request = [Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($url)

$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectory

$response = $request.GetResponse()

$reader   = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream()

$reader.ReadToEnd()

$reader.Close()

$response.Close()

}

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webclient.BaseAddress = $ftpPath

$files = Get-FTPDir $ftpPath

$latest = $Files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$latest